# In RichFaces, While using Email validation I am getting NullPointer Exception?

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, richfaces

**BeanClass code is:**

```
       public void validEmail(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
                Object value) throws Exception  
       {

                  //Set the email pattern string
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");

          //Match the given string with the pattern
          Matcher m = p.matcher(email);

          //check whether match is found 
          boolean matchFound = m.matches();

          if (matchFound)
            System.out.println("Valid Email Id.");
          else
            System.out.println("Invalid Email Id.");
       }
```

**.xhtml Code is:**

```
<h:inputText title="Enter Email Address" value="#{registerBean.email}" id="eMail" required="true" validator="#{registerBean.validEmail}">
<rich:ajaxValidator event="oninputblur"/>

</h:inputText>
<rich:message for="eMail"/>
```

**Exception is:**

```
/Register.xhtml @68,138 validator="#{registerBean.validEmail}": java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**How can i rectify this!**

Comment: check why registerBean is null at that point of execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to validate the `value` which is been **passed in** as method argument, not the local variable `email`, simply because it isn't been set yet (it has first to be validated!). It will be set only after validation phase, namely the update model values phase.

So, replace

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
```

by

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
```

Comment: how can i get the value from the .xhtml page to my bean?

Comment: i given whole class,Please check it out.

Comment: I've given the whole answer. Please check it out. Just modify the variable in the particular code line as demonstrated in the answer.